# Muestra en consol System.Int32[]

Tags: c#, array, recursión

```
public static int[] Invertir(int[] vector)
    {
        if (vector.Length == 1) return vector;
        else
        {
            int[] vector1 = { vector[vector.Length - 1] };
            int[] vector2 = new int[vector.Length - 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < vector2.Length; i++) vector2[i] = vector[i];
            return vector1.Concat(Invertir(vector2)).ToArray();
        }
```

AL imprimir el metodo en el program,
`namespace Recursividad_2
{
internal class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{

```
        int [] vector = new int[4];
        vector[0] = 1;
        vector[1] = 2;
        vector[2] = 3;
        vector[3] = 4;
     
        Console.WriteLine("invertir: " + Operaciones.Invertir(vector));





        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}
`

Muestra en consola, inivertir: system.int 32[] y no  muestra lo esperado.

Answer (score 1):

EL error esta en que estas imprimiendo el arreglo y no los datos que contiene el mismo para solucionarlo tienes que recorer el arreglo e imprimir sus valores de esta manera:

```
int[] array = Operaciones.Invertir(vector);
for(int i = 0; i < array.lenght; i++){
   //Accedemos al valor almacenado en el arreglo en el indice i
   Console.WriteLine(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: con razón, gracias

Answer (score 1):

Aqui otras opciones para "imprimir" en consola el arreglo ([dejo el ejemplo online aquí](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zs1KoZ))

Realizando el [foreach de la clase Array > Array.Foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.foreach?view=net-6.0) que recibe el arreglo y un ["action"](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.action-1?view=net-6.0) (que basicamente es un evento de un parametro y no devuelve valor)

```
Array.ForEach(array, Console.WriteLine);
```

O concatenando en una linea ([con el metodo Join de clase/alias string](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0))

```
Console.WriteLine("[{0}]", string.Join(", ", array));
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- Ejemplo online de imprimir array por consola > https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zs1KoZ
- [Array.Foreach](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.array.foreach?view=net-6.0)
- [string.Join](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-6.0)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda